# monacaで常駐アプリにするにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: javascript, android, monaca

アプリを作ったのですが、常駐というか定期的にコマンドを呼び出しを行いたいのですが、アプリを止めるとそれができません。どうしたら定期的な呼び出しを行えますか？

Answer (score 1):

アプリをバックグラウンドで動作させたいということでしょうか？
Monacaではバックグラウンドでのアプリの実行とその開発のサポートを行っていないと
Monacaドキュメントに記載してあります。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/faq/application/#can-i-develop-applications-that-run-in-the-background